# PowerShell Increases Disk Size as Desired but Throwing Errors Without any Problems

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, disk-space, window, powershell-5.0

This script loads a .csv file and  iterates through a list of VM's and checks free disk space and if below a certain amount in GB, increases disk space to that specified in the script. If the free space is already the desired amount, it writes to the console that hard disk space is a specified amount. The disk size changes and can be seen in the configure tab. The size is not allocated yet. I run another script for that. I would like to know why this is throwing this error and how I can remedy it. While the script does exactly what it is supposed to do, it gives an error as follows:

```
Resize-Partition : Size Not Supported
 
Extended information:
The partition is already the requested size.
 
Activity ID: {7f77f10d-2ae4-43d6-b6f1-ddbff4778f0d}
At line:44 char:1
+ Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_Partition) [Resize-Partition], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 4097,Resize-Partition
```

The script I use is below:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType = '3'" | 
Select-Object -Property DeviceID, DriveType, VolumeName, 
@{L='FreeSpaceGB';E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace /1GB)}},
@{L="Capacity";E={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}}

if (((Get-Volume -DriveLetter C).Size)/1GB -lt 80)
{
Write-Host "Hard Disk Space is less than 60."##Task Change Disk Size
##Variable clear
$csvobjects = @()
$cskobject = @()
$network = @()
$isalive = @()

#Get VM's to add disk space to
#$GetFreeSpace = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter DriveType=3 | Select-Object DeviceID, @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}, @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}

#Export to CSV

#$dateTime | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "D:\_Tools\PowerShell_CLI_HardDriveExpand-DiskFreeSpace-$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmssff").csv" -Append

##Import VM name(s)
$csvobjects = Import-CSV -path C:\Temp\CSK-11519DISK-1.csv

Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false

connect-viserver -server anyuser.anydomain.com -User anyuser@anydomain.com 

foreach ($csvobject in $csvobjects){
##Variable clear
$network = @()
$isalive = @()
##Pre-change data gathering
$beforechange = (GET-VM -Name $csvobject.vmname | FT -auto CapacityGB|out-string)
##Stop VM
GET-VM -Name $csvobject.vmname | Get-HardDisk -Name 'Hard disk 1' | Set-HardDisk -CapacityGB 80 -Confirm:$false
start-sleep -s 60

# Variable specifying the drive you want to extend
$drive_letter = "C"

# Script to get the partition sizes and then resize the volume
$size = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $drive_letter)
Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax
}

}
else
{
Write-Host "Hard Disk Space is greater than 60."
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's already at the max size. Can you call Get-Partition first to check if the current size is already the same as the maxsize value from Get-PartitionSupportedSize?

Comment: @HelpingHand That is the weird thing. It gives that error but it is not already that size. It does check the drive with the if statement and resizes the disk. That is the problem with the error. It says it's already that size but it isn't.